# being redirected to wrong loginUrl -> account/login instead of account/LOGON

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a strange error I have never run into before.

I secured a controller with:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")] 
public class LoggingController : Controller
```

When a non-admin user tries to access any protected content, they are redirected to:

http://localhost:50501/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2flogging

note: account/**login** and NOT account/***logon***

The AccountController.Login action does not exist.

web.config has:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

I can of course implement the Login action and redirect to Logon.
I am just puzzled and would like to know why this happens.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Search your project for login - it has to be specified somewhere. Is there any other web.config value overriding this (maybe looking at a child root and the parent value is being used)
Also is there any redirect that is happening? Are there any defaults set in your machine's web.config?
Is your default url on the project set to be a /login?

Install glimpse route debugger to see which route is being used for this page as well.

**EDIT**:
A little more research yields a known issue.
Check out this link:
[ASP.NET MVC issue with configuration of forms authentication section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087300/asp-mvc-problem-with-configuration-of-forms-authentication-section)

Theres a bug in mvc 3 beta - are you running the beta bits? 
Also notice the mentioned item in the above url for RTM bits:

```
<add key="loginUrl" value="~/LogOn" />
```

Also check out
http://forums.asp.net/p/1616153/4138366.aspx

**EDIT 2**

Below is a solid comment about a potential source of this from @santiagoIT (upvote his comment please if the specifics help you)

Today I discovered the root of this problem: I had added 'deployable dependency' on 'ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor Syntax'. This adds a reference to: WebMatrix.Data.dll This assembly has a class with a static constructor that does the following: static FormsAuthenticationSettings(){ FormsAuthenticationSettings.LoginUrlKey = "loginUrl"; FormsAuthenticationSettings.DefaultLoginUrl = "~/Account/Login";} That explains!

Comment: I did search for login but nothing turned up. I'll try your suggestions tomorrow. I am using wcf web api that is the only thing I would consider out of the ordinary. stilll very puzzled...

Comment: Thx! I added <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Account/Logon" /> to the appSetting and it worked.
I sure hope I am not running mvc 3 beta.
My System.Web.Mvc.dll shows v3.0.0.0. Is this the beta version?

Comment: I checked on another machine using the same source. Redirect works fine without the need to modify the web.config. So my machine has beta 3 installed somewhere. Very odd though as I set it up a few weeks ago and I would have never (consciously) installed a beta version of mvc....

Comment: Today I discovered the root of this problem:
I had added 'deployable dependency' on 'ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor Syntax'.
This adds a reference to: WebMatrix.Data.dll
This assembly has a class with a static constructor that does the following:

static FormsAuthenticationSettings(){ 

FormsAuthenticationSettings.LoginUrlKey = "loginUrl";

 FormsAuthenticationSettings.DefaultLoginUrl = "~/Account/Login";}

That explains!

Comment: hmm interesting. Was this a webmatrix sourced website?

Comment: No it was not. It is a asp.net mvc site, but in the past I had used some functionallity in the webmatrix dll's (grid) therefore I added the deployable dependency. Now I know better ;-)

Comment: I added the `app key` and that worked for me - I had 'deployable dependancy' also, (no ref to webmatrix though), but even after I removed all the references, I still had this problem. Weird

Comment: @Matt Did you manually delete the assemblies from the bin folder too? Just removing them from _bin_deployableAssemblies and even doing a clean solution is not enough.

Comment: We were deploying a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application today that is using the Razor syntax and were experiencing a problem similar. Adding the key for loginUrl works to redirect you back to the login page but the WebMatrix DLLs had to be removed completly or Forms Auth with some of our MVC areas was not working properly. So, if your login page works but you're having issues with Forms Auth then try removing the WebMatrix DLLs from the bin folder.

Comment: @Adam Tuliper: I suggest moving the information in the comment about deployable dependency into the answer. this was also the root of the problem for me, and also offers an explanation to the solution. its nice to know _why_ it works.

Comment: @ Adam Tuliper - MSFT:I had the same problem and remove WebMatrix.Data.dll and the problem was solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: I updated to mvc4 from mvc3 and began receiving the aforementioned behavior. `<add key="loginUrl" value="~/LogOn" />` set the proper functionality for me.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me and I'm using MVC 3

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Account/LogOn" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Also I found that adding the followinf part to the web config (only during debugging the config) helped speed up my debugging as had to authenticate for ANY page.

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" /> <!-- remove after debugging -->
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just simply remove the WebMatrix dll if they are present in your deployed bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it this way

1) Go ot IIS

2) Select your Project

3) Click on "Authentication"

4) Click on "Anonymous Authentication" > Edit > select "Application pool identity" instead of "Specific User".

5) Done.