# Request redirect to /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f since MVC 3 install on server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

We have an internal ASP.NET Webforms application running on a Windows 2008/IIS7 server which has been running fine until we installed MVC3.

Now any requests redirect to /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f.

The website is Webforms not MVC. Because it is an internal only site we have Windows Authentication enabled for the root folder.

We have several other websites on the same server that have not been affected by this problem, but this is the only site where the root folder is set to Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the following lines to the AppSettings section of my web.config file:

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

Comment: OMG. What a pain in the a$$.

The [MVC3 Release Notes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034230) say:

    **When you upgrade an ASP.NET MVC 2 project to ASP.NET MVC 3**, make sure to add the following to the appSettings section of the Web.config file:
    `<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />`

Comment: Absolutely stumbled across this fix! Thanks

Comment: It did solve the problem for Chrome and Firefox. In IE, not even an authentication prompt... Did anyone experience something similar?

Comment: this seemed to work at first but redirect came back. also not seeing WebMatrix anywhere.

Comment: Tried first to insert the two keys above in web.config. That worked. Then saw a WebMatrix.Data.dll in my bin folder. After I removed reference to this, the redirection to /Account/Login? went away again. This particular nuget package is at time of writing marked as legacy (I don't know how it got installed).

Answer (score 33):

I fixed it this way

1. Go to IIS
2. Select your Project
3. Click on "Authentication"
4. Click on "Anonymous Authentication" > Edit > select "Application
   pool identity" instead of "Specific User".
5. Done.

Comment: Surprisingly, this worked even though I had disabled "Anonymous Authentication".

Answer (score 8):

Just **remove**

```
 <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

from your web.config file

that did for me

Comment: Thank you. I tried all other things but your solution fixed my problem.

Answer (score 7):

Updated answer for MVC 4, heavily borrowed from this page and [ASP.NET MVC issue with configuration of forms authentication section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087300/asp-net-mvc-issue-with-configuration-of-forms-authentication-section/22542911) (and answered on both pages)

```
<appSettings>
   ...
   <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
</appSettings>

...

<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="43200" /> <!--43,200 in minutes - 30 days-->
</authentication>
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me, thank you.  I'm much more comfortable using this fix than:

<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>

Since the implications of these for site security are not 100% clear .

Answer (score 4):

It's resolved the IIS request auto redirect to default page(`default.aspx` or login page)

By adding the following lines to the AppSettings section of my `web.config` file:

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution was to add the tag

> [AllowAnonymous]

over my GET request for the Register page. It was originally missing from the code I was mantaining!

Answer (score 2):

A solve this adding in the option defaultURL the path my application

```
<forms loginUrl="/Users/Login" protection="All" timeout="2880" name="001WVCookie" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="/Home/Index" cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

We added some WCF SOAP related things to an existing IIS site and it caused this problem, with the site refusing to honour the web.config authentication redirect.

We tried the various fixes listed without success, and invented a work around of mapping the new weird URL back to the one we've been using for years:

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
<add mappedUrl="~/loginout.aspx" url="~/Account/Login"/>
</urlMappings>
```

That worked but it's ugly. Eventually we traced it down to a web.config entry added by Visual Studio some time earlier:

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
```

As we'd been unable to work out precisely what that does, we took it out, which solved the problem for us immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Open web.config,then Change

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

To

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

change to  ~/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Be ware with this:

```
RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
  filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After 4 hours, of trying everything... Windows 2008 R2 the files were green in Window Explorer. The files were marked for encryption and arching that came from the zip file. unchecking those options in the file property fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works then add     authentication mode="Windows"                           in your    system.web attribute in your Web.Config file. hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Drezus - you solved it for me.  Thanks so much.

In your AccountController, login should look like this:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar setup, identical problem. Some installations would work, but most would start redirecting (http 302) to /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f after a successful login, even though we're not using Forms Authentication. In my case after trying everything else, the solution was to switch the Application Pool Managed Pipeline Mode from from Integrated to Classic, which cleared up the problem immediately.