# ReturnUrl issue with asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have to deal with a legacy asp.net mvc app, which is not configured as I am used to. After a normal logout via:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

and

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

the URI contains:

```
ReturnUrl=%2f
```

This is not usually the case. How can I suppress this?

Alternatively, when I try to access a page that requires authentication/authorization the login page appears but no appropriate ReturnUrl= is generated (i.e. the URI stays as it is).

Is this an IIS issue, which I have read somewhere, or is the asp.net FormsAuthenticationModule not properly configured? Thanks.

Comment: May be related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205368/request-redirect-to-account-loginreturnurl-2f-since-mvc-3-install-on-server

Comment: Came across this before posting ... don't think so though.

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.0. Thanks.

Comment: How does it behave in Cassini?  If it fails there as well, then it is not an IIS problem.  If it has proper returnUrl there, then it likely is IIS problem.  Can you post your authentication element of system.web in web.config file?

Comment: Does it put anything else if you set another controller/method? If being redirected to Index/Home it wouldn't need to specify a return url as it would go here by default after logging in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReturnUrl is added during an unauthorized redirect.  Someone appears to be redirecting the root url (/) to itself or to Home/Index.  %2f is the encoded form of "/".

I would check the authorization section of the web.config for something that looks wrong.

Comment: In my case my returnUrl was pointing to LogOff on Login.  It turned out the LogOff Action needed `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute

Answer (score 0):

This is depends on you routing, right? If you have this as you last route configuration:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
 "Default", 
 "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works then add authentication mode="Windows" in your system.web attribute in your Web.Config file. hope it will work for you.