# mvc 5 redirection error

Tags: c#, forms-authentication

In the last week I'm have a real problem with external login of mvc 5.

I'm have a project that allow user to connet with Facebook. After filling the AppId and AppSecret in the "Startup.Auth.cs" file, I'm tried to connet with facebook login

default mvc template Account controller.

But, I'm getting strange problem. After pressing the Facebook button, the current page ("http:// localhost:6987/Account/Login") redirect to another page ("http:// localhost:6987/Account/Login**?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fExternalLogin**").

I'm really have no clue why it's happen. I'm thought that maybe the ExternalLogin not marked with AllowAnonymous attribute, but it is marked with.

I'm tried to create an mvc 5 template project, filled my Facebook id's and it's working there! (same controller + Facebook id's).

Maybe you have any ideas what I'm have to check?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
Tried to fix it with this thread ([Request redirect to /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f since MVC 3 install on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205368/request-redirect-to-account-loginreturnurl-2f-since-mvc-3-install-on-server)):

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

It's now working, but still redirect to strange URL: http:// localhost:6987/**#*=***

Anyone know why?

Comment: So......much.......code. Please narrow this down to what really matters.

Comment: I upgraded my website from MVC4 TO mvc5 and got the same error. Your link fixed it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a problem like that and was caused because i changed the  to Form after I fixed it back to None, all worked

Comment: adding those two app keys didn't solve my problem but yours did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use OAuth mechanism?
When you authenticate users using Facebook, what could be happening is:

1. You redirect to facebook and let the control to facebook
2. Facebook authenticates the user as it is used to
3. Once authentication is done, Facebook wil redirect to callback auth method with user´s info you have required

I strongly recomend you to read about [OAuth](https://oauth.net/)

I hope It helps you