# It's back: Login.aspx not found

Tags: authentication, redirect, iis

This seems to be an old issue, but I'm now experiencing this in IIS 8.5:

[errormessage Login.aspx not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbYYc.png)

Tried some of the old work-arounds, but I guess this is a new issue with similar symptoms? It may be connected to running .NET 4.7.2?

When we run the app on Azure it works fine.

The app does seem to find WindowsLogin.aspx which is normal, but the redirect after that seems to go amiss.

Could have something to do with .NET 4.7.2

Any ideas?

Comment: May I know what kind of web application you are deploying? I don't think this error is related to .net 4.7.2. This error page is not responsed by IIS but .net application.According to error, please make sure that the PLANproducten folder and login page exist, and the login page is in the correct location.I recommend that you turn on the failed request tracking function to see where the problem occurred in the complete request process. Dou you use custom error page,authentication or redirection?If you use form authentication, could you show some part of code and config file,that's helpful

Comment: This is a .NET MVC web application. We don't have a "login" page, we have a "WindowsLogin" page. It's unclear where this redirect to "login.aspx" comes from. It works fine when the app is deployed to Azure, but this pops up when deployed in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this has to do with MVC 5 and WebApi2:

This is the solution: [MVC5 Redirects to Login.aspx when using Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078482/mvc5-redirects-to-login-aspx-when-using-windows-authentication)

Comment: Please mark it as answer so that can help others with similar problems.