# ASP.NET MVC login ReturnUrl=%2F

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using C# with ASP.NET MVC5. I publish my app in Azure and everything worked properly. Until i launch a new update.

After that, when i try to login i am redirected to the login page again, and the returned url is Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F.

However, if a delete the app from azure and re-publish it, it works, even with the previous update that break the login system (by the way, i didn't touch in the account controller).

i know there are 2 topics about this problem, i tried everything and nothing seems to work. I guess that they are outdated.

1º: [ASP.NET MVC issue with configuration of forms authentication section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087300/asp-net-mvc-issue-with-configuration-of-forms-authentication-section/22542911)

2º: [Request redirect to /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f since MVC 3 install on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205368/request-redirect-to-account-loginreturnurl-2f-since-mvc-3-install-on-server)

Anyone knows how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Try restarting the application pool if Azure allows this...just a thought.

Comment: As far as i know you can't do that, but i restarted the app and the problem persists

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205368/request-redirect-to-account-loginreturnurl-2f-since-mvc-3-install-on-server) helps.

Comment: Can you capture the network in your browsers dev tool? Then we could see what kind of redirections are happening.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't do that. I create a new one and copied all files manually :( it worked. I did that because the app is in early stages, it take me a couple of hours. Right now i can update as many times as i need without any problem. thanks anyway